# Batch Apex Class to update lookup field

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I really need help with my code. I am trying to update Account records with lookup field to right Pricebook2 based on Customer_Price_Group__c field on Account and Pricebook2.

Customer_Price_Group__c is on Account and on Pricebook2. I need to fetch and fill the lookup on Account record.

```
    global class pricebookOnAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Customer_Price_Group__c, Price_book__c FROM Account WHERE Actual_Pricebook__c = FALSE AND Customer_Price_Group__c != null]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> scope) {
        List<Account> accRec = [Select id, Customer_Price_Group__c, Price_book__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Price_Group__c != null AND Actual_Pricebook__c = FALSE AND Id = :scope];
        
        Map<id, Pricebook2> pricebooks = new Map<id, Pricebook2>();
        for(Account record: accRec) {
            pricebooks.put(record.Price_book__c, null);
        }
        pricebooks.putAll([SELECT id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Year_is_actual__c = TRUE AND Customer_Price_Group__c = :accRec AND Id = :pricebooks.keySet()]);
        for(Account a:accRec) {
            a.Price_book__c = pricebooks.get(a.id);
        }
        update accRec;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Now I am getting errors:

Line 12: Invalid bind expression type of Account for column of type String

Line 14: Illegal assignment from Pricebook2 to Id

WORKING CODE:

```
    global class pricebookOnAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Customer_Price_Group__c, Price_book__c FROM Account WHERE Actual_Pricebook__c = FALSE AND Customer_Price_Group__c != null]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> scope) {
        List<Account> accRec = [Select id, Customer_Price_Group__c, Price_book__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Price_Group__c != null AND Actual_Pricebook__c = FALSE AND Id = :scope];
        
       Map<String, Id> pricebookByGroup = new Map<String, Id>();
       Set<String> priceGroups = new Set<String>();
       for(Account record: accRec) {
          priceGroups.add(record.Customer_Price_Group__c);
       }
       for(Pricebook2 record: [SELECT Customer_Price_Group__c FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Year_Is_Actual__c = true AND Customer_Price_Group__c = :priceGroups]) {
          pricebookByGroup.put(record.Customer_Price_Group__c, record.Id);
       }
       for(Account record: accRec) {
        record.Price_Book__c = pricebookByGroup.get(record.Customer_Price_Group__c);
       }
update accRec;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Line 12: Invalid bind expression type of Account for column of type String

Customer_Price_Group__c isn't a lookup to Account, and you can't bind a List of Sobject unless you want the Id. You need to extract those values:

```
Set<String> customerPriceGroups = new Set<String>();
for(Account acc: accRec) {
  customerPriceGroups.add(acc.Customer_Price_Group__c);
}
```

...

```
WHERE ... Customer_Price_Group__c = :customerPriceGroups
```

## Line 14: Illegal assignment from Pricebook2 to Id

The map contains a Pricebook2 value, not an Id, so the code should look like:

```
a.Price_Book__c = pricebooks.get(a.Id).Id;
```

However, this won't work; you're trying to get the pricebook by the account Id. All your code will accomplish is wiping out all the pricebook data.

Instead, you need something more like this:

```
Map<String, Id> pricebookByGroup = new Map<String, Id>();
Set<String> priceGroups = new Set<String>();
for(Account record: accRec) {
  priceGroups.add(record.Customer_Price_Group__c);
}
for(Pricebook2 record: [SELECT Customer_Price_Group__c FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Year_Is_Actual__c = true AND Customer_Price_Group__c = :priceGroups]) {
  pricebookByGroup.put(record.Customer_Price_Group__c, record.Id);
}
for(Account record: accRec) {
  a.Price_Book__c = pricebookByGroup.get(record.Customer_Price_Group__c);
}
update accRec;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're incredible. Everything works perfect! I will add the whole code in my post, maybe someone will use it! Thank you again!